# MongoDB SHARDING_FILTER in plan

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a problem on Sharded Cluster. I'm testing performance to compare between Sharded and Replica Set.

I have inserted data to Shard 1 directly without mongos and then query it by aggregate query but I cannot found it. I checked in explain plan that shows "SHARDING_FILTER" in stage on Primary shard but doesn't have that in Secondary when I checked explain plan.

What's configuration to control about it?

MongoDB version : 3.0.12

Comment: But I query by find command that shows "winningPlan" value is "FETCH" and can get the result on both nodes.

Comment: Does no one have this experience? :(

Comment: As my assumption, if have some connection from MongoS to connect to each Replica set that will change plan to SHARDING_FILTER, so I tried to connect another node in the same Replica set and check explain plan that still use normal "FILTER" not sharding so I reconfigured to set that node to primary and connect by mongoshell to that node directly, I can query it as my expectation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have inserted data to Shard 1 directly without mongos and then query it by aggregate query but I cannot found it.

It's not entirely clear what your performance comparison is, but irrespective you should always interact with data via `mongos` for a sharded cluster.

The role of `mongos` includes keeping track of the sharded cluster metadata (as cached from the config servers), observing data inserts/updates/deletions, and routing requests. Bypassing `mongos` will lead to potential complications in collection/data visibility (as you have observed) because you are skipping some of the expected data management infrastructure for your sharded deployment.

> I checked in explain plan that shows "SHARDING_FILTER" in stage on Primary shard but doesn't have that in Secondary when I checked explain plan.

Secondary reads are eventually consistent, so the state of data on a given secondary may not necessarily match the current sharded cluster metadata. This becomes more problematic with many shards: with a secondary read preference results can potentially be combined from secondaries with significant differences in replication lag.

For consistent queries for a sharded cluster you should always use primary reads (which is the default behaviour) via `mongos`. Queries against primaries through `mongos` may include a `SHARDING_FILTER` stage which filters result documents that are not owned by the current shard (for example, due to migrations in progress where documents need to transiently exist on both a donor and target shard).

As at MongoDB 3.4, secondaries do not have the ability to filter results because they'd need to maintain a separate view of the cluster metadata which matches their eventually consistent state. There's a relevant Jira issue to watch/upvote: [SERVER-5931 - Secondary reads in sharded clusters need stronger consistency](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5931). I currently would not recommend secondary reads in a sharded cluster (or in general) without careful consideration of the impact of eventual consistency on your use case. For the general case, please read [Can I use more replica nodes to scale?](http://www.askasya.com/post/canreplicashelpscaling/).

> What's configuration to control about it?

Use the default [read preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) (`primary` reads) and always interact with your sharded deployment through `mongos`.